# nHibernate.IQueryOver removing sub class left join

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, nhibernate

I have a query with an inner join between two objects (`BagDto` and `ItemDto`) where `ItemDto` also has at least one parent with type of `LocationDto`. Here are the class definitions:

```
    public class BagDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        /* other properties for bag comming from oracle DB */
        public IEnumerable<ItemDto> Items { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BagId { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
        public BagDto Bag { get; set; }
        public LocationDto Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class LocationDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double SquareMeters { get; set; }
        public string CountyName { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<ItemDto> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

In my query I do not want any kind of Location data to get and only `BagDto` and `ItemDto` is really what I would like to query. The mapping of all three objects are okay and I do not want to change those. I also would not like to create inheritance to separate `LocationDto` out (ie.: `ItemDto` will not contains `LocationDto` but `ItemWithLocationDto` will).

---

Here is the query:

```
public IEnumerable<BagDto> GetBagsWithAvailableType()
{
   ItemDto itemDtoAlias = null;
   Session.QueryOver<BagDto>()
          .Where(x.CreatedDate   <= DateTime.UtcNow)
          .JoinAlias(x => x.Items, () => itemDtoAlias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
          .Where(
              () => itemDtoAlias.Type  == "A")
          .List();
}
```

Using nHibernate Profiler the following query is generated:

```
SELECT this_.ID,
   this_.COLOR,
   this_.TYPE,
   this_.CREATEDDATE,
   item1_.ID,
   item1_.BAG_ID,
   item1_.LOCATION_ID,
   location2_.ID,
   location2_.NAME,
   location2_.SQUAREMETERS,
   location2_.COUNTYNAME
FROM   BAG this_
   inner join ITEM item1_
   on this_.ID = item1_.BAG_ID
   left outer join LOCATION location2_
   on item1_.LOCATION_ID = location2_.ID
WHERE  (this_.CREATEDDATE <= TIMESTAMP '2021-04-07 16:23:54')
   and (item1_.TYPE = 'A')
```

Anybody knows a way how to get rid of the left outer join related to the LOCATION? I would like to specify this in the query but google all the day for it still no solution. Thanks for the help!

P. S.: writting all this query in plain SQL and call it from the code is a bad practice. Our codeguides are not allowing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without mappings it's not clear why `Location` is added to the query in a first place. Assuming it's added due to `fetch="join"` mapping for `Location` property you can skip it in a query with `SelectMode.Skip` (available since NHibernate 5.2):

```
ItemDto itemDtoAlias = null;
   Session.QueryOver<BagDto>()
          .Where(x.CreatedDate   <= DateTime.UtcNow)
          .JoinAlias(x => x.Items, () => itemDtoAlias, NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
          .Fetch(SelectMode.Skip, () => itemDtoAlias.Location)
...
```

See description of all `SelectMode` options [here](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/pull/1599)